# I cannot find relevant information to use a tool for collecting data and the author isn't responding. What do I do?

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate, covid-19, tools, correspondence

I am conducting a survey to measure the impact of social distancing on family dynamics, for which I came across a tool that fits my study perfectly. However, I am not able to find information on the scoring key, manual and interpretation, and I'm unable to contact the author. I couldn't find any other tool or papers that have used the CHES questionnaire and I'm running extremely short on time. How do I proceed?

Comment: Pick a different tool?

Answer (score 4):

The only option I see is to use a different tool. You think this one is perfectly suited for you, but actually it isn't, it's incomplete because you're missing the other half of it.

Typically other options would include looking for other authors that have used it or finding other papers that might describe the procedure more completely, but you've already said this is not possible. You've already tried to contact the author without success. You're running out of time so it seems past time to cut your losses and move on.

Answer (score 1):

If the survey is useful, then use it to collect data, cite the author as appropriate, and develop your own scoring to suit your needs.